# How do you create a self-signed certificate for use in object signing?

Tags: openssl, code-signing, digital-certificate

I am trying to create an object-signing certificate myself instead of paying Verisign or some other company hundreds of dollars. I am using linux (specifically 64bit OpenSUSE 11.1) so it would be best if I could create it in that environment. I have successfully created self-signed certificates for Apache to use for https connections using openssl. However, I cannot find what I need to do different to make it this special "object-signing" certificate.

Specifically I need an object-signing certificate to digitally sign some javascript code so that it can use extra privileges. Mozilla javascript signing is described here : http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html#signing, however the link that says it describes the basics of object signing is dead.

Any help would be appreciated on the differences between an apache https ssl cert and an object-signing cert, or a how-to or faq or something on the steps to take using openssl or some other similar utility.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73702334/1364242

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wlug.org.nz/JavaScript

This should create a signing certificate : 
signtool -d ~/.mozilla -p password -G certname