# How to create a self-signed code signing certificate from a CSR?

Tags: openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

The title says it all. All the articles I could find was either about generating a self-signed SSL certificate, or not considering a CSR. My requirement is simple: generate a self-signed code signing certificate that I can use with signtool.exe from a CSR for testing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I expect this question to be a duplicate but I could not find a concise answer so I am offering this as a more complete one using OpenSSL to generate [x509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) self signed certificates for code signing (or any other purpose).

Steps:

1. Generate a CA (Certificate Authority) key
2. Generate an x509 CA certificate (DER encoding)
3. Create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) template
4. Generate a CSR using the CSR template
5. Create a signing certificate template
6. Generate an x509 signing certificate and key pair (DER enconding)
7. (optional) Convert DER to PKCS12 format (Windows needs this)
8. (optional) View your work

*I will use a fake company (The Company Ltd) that is not related in any way to a real organisation*

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER,_CER_and_DER_compared) for a clarification of BER, DER and CER formats.  Note .cer is often used as a file extension for a DER file - Doh!
Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) about PKCS12 format

1 - Generate a CA key

```bash
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096
```

Give the root CA key a password and don't forget it!!

2 - Create an x509 CA certificate (DER encoding)

```bash
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
```

Enter details for: [example]

- Country: [UK]
- Province: [England]
- City: [London]
- Organisation: [The Company Ltd]
- Division: [Engineering]
- Common Name: [The Company Ltd - Engineering Root Certificate]
- email: [admin@the-company.com]

3 - Edit CSR Template : ***code_sign_csr.conf***

```
[ req ]
default_bits  = 2048      # RSA key size
encrypt_key   = yes       # Protect private key
default_md    = sha256    # MD to use
utf8          = yes       # Input is UTF-8
string_mask   = utf8only  # Emit UTF-8 strings
prompt        = yes       # Prompt for DN
distinguished_name = codesign_dn # DN template
req_extensions     = codesign_reqext # Desired extensions

[ codesign_dn ]
commonName      = the-company.com
commonName_max  = 64

[ codesign_reqext ]
keyUsage             = critical,digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage     = critical,codeSigning
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
```

4 - Generate a CSR using the template

```bash
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout testsign.key -sha256 -nodes -out testsign.csr -subj "/CN=The Company Engineering Code Sign Cert" -config code_sign_csr.conf
```

5 - Create a signing certificate template: ***code_sign_cert.conf***

```
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
subjectAltName         = @alt_names
extendedKeyUsage       = codeSigning

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = the-company.com
```

6 - Generate a x509 signing cert and key pair by signing the CSR with the CA certificate

```bash
openssl x509 -req -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -in testsign.csr -out testsign.crt -days 365 -CAcreateserial -extfile code_sign_cert.conf
```

***The same process in (5) and (6) is used to generate further certificates.***

7 - (optional) convert x509 certs to PKCS12

```bash
openssl pkcs12 -export -out testsign.p12 -inkey testsign.key -in testsign.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out rootCA.p12 -inkey rootCA.key -in rootCA.crt
```

8 - (optional) view your work

```bash
openssl x509 -in testsign.crt -noout -text
openssl x509 -in rootCA.crt -noout -text
```

***Note and verify the Issuer and Subject***

Now supply the rootCA certificate to the clients that need to validate the certificate.

Supply the rootCA certificate and generated certificate(s) to the server, code author, emailer, etc.

***Store the CA signing key in a very safe place and don't share it or forget where you put it..... (I always find that bit the hardest).***

A note on [Subject Alt Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)

- For email signing, the Subject Alt Name (SAN) must match the email
  address
- For DNS signing it must match the domain name(s) and/or include a wildcard.
- For a server it could match the IP address and/or canonical name assuming that matching and accessible DNS records exist.

Comment: In your step 5 I had to add `extendedKeyUsage=codeSigning` to the `code_sign_cert.conf` file, or the `CodeSign.crt` would be missing the `Code Signing` extension (intended purpose).

Comment: Thanks @SteffenSH.  I have amended it.  Was a while ago I posted this so I really can't remember even why I wrote it. :o)  So I am not sure if that omission is a copy paste error or down to implementation.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to copy the extensions from the csr to the crt, add the option `-copy_extensions=copyall`

e.g.

```
openssl x509 -req -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -in testsign.csr -out testsign.crt -days 365 -CAcreateserial -extfile code_sign_cert.conf -copy_extensions=copyall
```

Comment: Gary, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: A bit harsh on @Gary, with a rep of 1.  I know it's not strict SE, but he was just trying to be helpful.  I have upvoted his addition as compensation.