# Osslsigncode verify fails even though rootCA certificate is added to the trust store

Tags: openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have been looking for a way to sign an executable so that Windows stops saying that my own executable is a danger to my system.

A few information first:

- I don't want to publish my program so I went for a self-signed certificate.
- I am doing this from Linux (Arch-based)
- I know I can just tell Windows to stop dictating me how to use my computer, the thing is I want to share my program to people who should not do that for safety reasons (but can install my certificate).
- I don't do this on Windows yet because my guess is that if it fails on Linux, it will fail on Windows.

---

**What I did:**

I did not know anything about certificates so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73702334/21893395) to create all the (apparently) required certificates (steps 1 to 6 only).

Then, I signed the executable the way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29073957/21893395) suggests (the first way to sign).

I tried verifying it with the following command:

```
$ osslsigncode verify -in <myprogram>-signed.exe
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
PKCS7_verify error
40377E953E700000:error:10800075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:296:Verify error: unable to get local issuer certificate
Signature verification: failed
```

On the internet, I have found two possible reasons for this error:

1. My code sign certificate configuration (see below) had the basic constraints CA:FALSE which apparently (I can't find the post...) may have been wrong.
   Changing it to CA:TRUE did not change anything.

```
# code_sign_cert.conf
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
basicConstraints       = CA:TRUE
subjectAltName         = @alt_names
extendedKeyUsage       = codeSigning

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = the-company.com # I don't even know what to put here
```

2. My `rootCA.crt` was not added to the trusted ones, so I added it with this command:

```
# trust anchor --store rootCA.crt
```

And even ran `$ sudo update-ca-trust` just in case, and nothing changed at all.
I can find the certificate (named after me instead of "rootCA") in the `/etc/ca-certificates/` folder so it seems to have worked.

But in the end I still get the same error.

I'm at a loss because I'm confused with all the certificate formats, I don't know where to look at anymore.

**Does anyone have a clue as to why the verification fails?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the trusted certificates to osslsigncode with the `-CAfile` parameter:

```
osslsigncode verify -CAfile full-chain.pem -in <myprogram>-signed.exe
```